# Putting div in the middle of another div

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I have created an html page and I have used `<center>` to make it to come at the center of the div like as shown below, but the error alert message is not coming at the center of the portlet-body

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0rgOdCQW98SBU8FnbZf?p=preview)**

```
<div class="portlet-body">
  <center>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean text is not centered inside red box?

Comment: @NenadVracar no, actually I have the content of portlet-body to be in centered and at the middle

Comment: .portlet-body{
  text-align:center;
}

Comment: still not working @Nasco.Chachev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot vertical center any element directly unless
 - All parents have 100% height.

There are some neat solutions to allow vertical centering, and one latest addition to CSS3 standards called - Flexbox

Some popular tricks:

**Use CSS Table-Cell layout**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <!-- You apply 'vertical-align: center' property to table-cell class -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Use Flex Layout**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Read further: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

**Use Ghost element**

Refer Chris Coyer here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: @AlexMan Flex is not supported in IE8 and IE9.
You can use either CSS Table cell trick (not real <table> elements) or the ghost element.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Unless, if you want to support IE8, best option is to use Javascript as fallback.

If I answered your doubt, kindly mark this as correct answer